# Can't get ButtonUI from UIManager to work

Tags: java, swing

I (and ChatGPT neither it seems) don't manage to use the ButtonUI property of the UIManager correctly. Here are two simple classes in the default package that I use. Only the button1, on which I set the CustomButtonUI  manually, is being displayed with orange or grey background. I expect button2 to have the same layout because of my UIManager.put(... statement. No Exception is thrown by the code.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class CustomButtonUIExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // UIManager-Registrierung
        UIManager.put("ButtonUI", CustomButtonUI.class.getName());

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Custom Button UI Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        System.out.println(UIManager.get("ButtonUI"));
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        button1.setUI(new CustomButtonUI());
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");

        frame.add(button1);
        frame.add(button2);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(800, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;

import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonUI;

public class CustomButtonUI extends BasicButtonUI {
    @Override
    protected void installDefaults(AbstractButton b) {
        System.out.println("installDefaults called");
        super.installDefaults(b);
        b.setBackground(Color.gray);

        b.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                b.setBackground(Color.orange);
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                b.setBackground(Color.gray);
            }
        });
    }
    
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
        super.paint(g, c);
    }
}
```

Comment: A quick glance shows that you and the AI never added the `CustomButtonUI` to `button2`. Simply add a new line `button2.setUI(new CustomButtonUI());` to your main class after button2 has been created.

Comment: But that's the whole point. I do not want to add the UI to every button manually in my code. That's why I am using the UIManager which should set this as default for all buttons. The manual setting for button1 was just to make sure that in general the CustomButtonUI works. I will update the question to make this more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Your `CustomButtonUI` class does not declare a `createUI` method, therefore it inherits the [method from `BasicButtonUI`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicButtonUI.html#createUI(javax.swing.JComponent)) which creates an instance of `BasicButtonUI`.

So a quick solution is to add a method like this to your `CustomButtonUI`.

```java
public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent c) {
    return new CustomButtonUI();
}
```

But as long as your UI instance does not contain component specific state, it can be a singleton. The same applies to the focus listener which can be implemented without containing a reference to the component. Then, you can add a correct cleanup to your UI implementation in a simple way:

```java
public class CustomButtonUI extends BasicButtonUI {
    static final CustomButtonUI INSTANCE = new CustomButtonUI();

    public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent c) {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    static final FocusListener FOCUS_LISTENER = new FocusListener() {
        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            e.getComponent().setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        }
  
        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            e.getComponent().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void installDefaults(AbstractButton b) {
        System.out.println("installDefaults called");
        super.installDefaults(b);
        b.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        b.addFocusListener(FOCUS_LISTENER);
    }

    @Override
    protected void uninstallDefaults(AbstractButton b) {
        super.uninstallDefaults(b);
        b.removeFocusListener(FOCUS_LISTENER);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, it works. Now I just need to understand better why. I will have to read a bit at the weekend. Thanks a lot!